# UITableView - Controlling or preventing the delete for a specific row in a section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to prevent the delete for every last row in every section of my UITableView control. I wrote the code which is working so far.

**Is there a way to prevent the delete button from appearing for a specific row in a specific section when in edit mode of UITableView?**

Here is the code :

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

    // If table view is asking to commit a delete command...
    if ( editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Prevent deleting the last row
        int length = [[[MyItemStore sharedStore] getItemsForGivenSection:section] count];

        // PREVENT LAST ROW FROM DELETING
        if ( row == length) {
            return;
        }

        NSArray *items = [[MyItemStore sharedStore] getItemsForGivenSection:section];
        MyItem *item = items[row];
        [[MyItemStore sharedStore] removeItemFromSection:item fromSection:section];

         //Also remove that row from Table view with animation
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: @[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a specific delegate method for specifying the editing style of a row. Return the "None" value for the desired row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Return FALSE for the last row
    if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1)
        return FALSE;
    }

    //Return TRUE for all other rows
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath` is too late as this gets called when the user already triggered the deletion. You can either return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` from `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` or set the `editingStyle` property of the `UITableViewCell`. Sounds like you want to go with the former and return none if it's the last row in each section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in the Table View Controller:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
           editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1)
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome! Please give a vote to my answer if it helped you.